# pandas : getting "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" when merging

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm merging 2 datasets in pandas but i get the error `"TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'".`

The command im running is :

```
merge_projects_task = pd.merge(df_data_task, 
                              df_data_projects,[['project_id','name']],
                              left_on='project_id', right_on='id')
```

"id" is a object type and "project_id" is also.  Any ideas whats happening here and how to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears, you might have an extra comma in your code:

```
merge_projects_task = pd.merge(df_data_task, 
                              df_data_projects[['project_id','name']],
                              left_on='project_id', right_on='id')
```